# Selecting 1.6M rows of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file with ~2.3M rows. I'd like save the subset (~1.6M) of the rows which have non-nan values in two columns inside the dataframe. I'd like to keep using pandas to do this. Right now, my code looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
catalog = pd.read_csv('catalog.txt')
slim_list = []
for i in range(len(catalog)):
    if (pd.isna(catalog['z'][i]) == False and pd.isna(catalog['B'][i]) == False):
        slim_list.append(i)
```

which holds the rows of `catalog` which have non-nan values. I then make a new catalog with those rows as entries

```
slim_catalog = pd.DataFrame(columns = catalog.columns)
for j in range(len(slim_list)):
    data = (catalog.iloc[j]).to_dict()
    slim_catalog = slim_catalog.append(data, ignore_index = True)
pd.to_csv('slim_catalog.csv')
```

This should, in principle, work. It's sped up a little by reading each row into a dict. However, it takes far, far too long to execute for all 2.3M rows. What is a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: did you try `dfx = df[df['z'].notnull()]` to see what it results in?

Comment: I think you could filter and save your dataset`catalog[(catalog['z'].notna()) & (catalog['B'].notna())].to_csv('slim_catalog.csv')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This **is the completely wrong way of doing this in pandas**.

Firstly, **never** iterate over some range, i.e. `for i in range(len(catalog)):` and then individually index into the row: `catalog['z'][i]`, that is incredibly inefficient.

Second, **do not** create a pandas.DataFrame using `pd.DataFrame.append` in a loop, that is a linear operation, so the entire thing will be quadratic time.

But you shouldn't be looping here to begin with. All you need is something like

```
catalog[catalog.loc[:, ['z', 'B']].notna().all(axis=1)].to_csv('slim_catalog.csv')
```

Or broken up to perhaps be more readable:

```
not_nan_zB = catalog.loc[:, ['z', 'B']].notna().all(axis=1)
catalog[not_nan_zB].to_csv('slim_catalog.csv')
```

Comment: This is why physicists should need a license to code :) - I'll try this once the catalog loads in (which it only does 50% of the time) and accept this if it works.

Comment: @user3517167 heh, I actually work with several physicists (by training). By now they are all solid coders, but definitely, a lot of people who are just thrown into the deep end of pandas etc will need to learn some stuff